# jQuery mobile group select & text box in one line

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm trying to group a selectbox and textbox side by side by side using jquery mobile. They are currently displaying below each other. I've tried control group within jquery, but to no avail.

I want to do something like this http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/widgets/forms/form-fieldcontain.html though with a select and drop, where this example shows a label and text box side by side.

Here is my current code. Any help appreciated.

```
<label style="margin-top:30px;background: #ffffff;">Mobile Number:</label>
                <select name="mobilePrefix" id="mobilePrefix">
                    <option value="">Mobile Prefix</option>
                    <option value="082">082</option>
                    <option value="083">083</option>
                    <option value="085">085</option>
                </select>
                <input class="required" name="mobileno" id="mobileno" value="" data-clear-btn="true" type="tel"/>
```

Comment: which jqm version are you using?

Comment: anyway, this is for jQM 1.4 http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/ccb6z/